# Icon not showing in launcher in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, .desktop

I have downloaded some software and created their `.desktop` files for GUI access. I have successfully created shortcuts, but they are showing system icons instead of the given path icon:

[image: apps without proper icons]

Here is code from the `Idea.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Idea
Comment=IDE
Exec=Software/ideaIE-2020.2.3/idea-IE-202.7660.52/bin/idea.sh
Icon=Software/ideaIE-2020.2.3/idea-IE-202.7660.52/bin/idea.svg
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass="jetbrains-idea-edu", "jetbrains-idea-edu"
Type=Application
Categories=IDE;
X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=true
```

Files have been stored in `~/.local/share/applications`.
Files are executable;
Execute the program on click.

Please suggest how I can solve this issue.

Comment: Path starting with 'Software' exists??

Comment: Yes, and when I click on that icon it executes the Program. Just icons are not showing

Comment: `ls Software` in a terminal whats the output?

Comment: Path of the icon file is probably not correct or the file is broken.

Comment: The path was correct but any problem has been solved Thank you for taking an interest

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved when I put my icon file in .local/share/icons folder

```
Version=1.0
Name=Idea
Comment=IDE
Exec=Software/ideaIE-2020.2.3/idea-IE-202.7660.52/bin/idea.sh
Icon=idea
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass="jetbrains-idea-edu", "jetbrains-idea-edu"
Type=Application
Categories=IDE;
X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=true
```